# Angular Dialog Box

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am wondering if it is possible to use Angular material's dialog box to pass a string directly into the method of the dialog.open ? I am new to angular and I have just one single error message to display on the dialog box. I also would like to add that I would not want to create a new HTML file for it specially to display a single error message :P 
Does anyone have any suggestions ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. In your component, pass in the variable like this

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(myDialogComponent, {data: this.myVariable});
```

Then in your dialog component, do this

```
import {MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
import {Inject} from '@angular/core';

export class myComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
  }
}

ngOnInit () {
  console.log(this.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the dialog component [allows you to specify an `<ng-template>` (see the `MatDialog#open` method)](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialog) containing the contents of the dialog that you want to display:

```html
<ng-template #yourDialog>
  <h2 matDialogTitle>Error</h2>
  <mat-dialog-content>
    <p>Could not load contents. Try again later.</p>
  </mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button mat-button matDialogClose>Dismiss</button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</ng-template>
```

Then the `yourDialog` template dialog can be referenced with a [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild):

```js
import { TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class YourComponent {
  @ViewChild('yourDialog') yourDialog: TemplateRef<any>;

  // ...

  showErrorDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(yourDialog);
  }
}
```

Optionally, you can [pass data](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component-) to a template dialog with the `let-data` attribute (as it will be available *implicitly* in the template):

```html
<ng-template #yourDialog let-data>
  <h2 matDialogTitle *ngIf="data?.title">{{ data.title }}</h2>
  <mat-dialog-content>
    <p *ngIf="data?.message">{{ data.message }}</p>
  <mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button mat-button matDialogClose>Dismiss</button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</ng-template>
```

```js
// ...
export class YourComponent {
  @ViewChild('yourDialog') yourDialog: TemplateRef<any>;

  // ...

  showErrorDialog(error: { title?: string, message?: string }) {
    this.dialog.open(yourDialog, {
      data: error
    });
  }
}
```